# Event to access item from an aggregation binding

Tags: sapui5

In my Controller doInit(), I create a JSON model and bind it to View
In my View, I use the created model in aggregation binding ( of IconTabBar)

My question is how do I access IconTabBar items in doInit() of Controller. Which event shall I use?

Thanks much.

Comment: Could you share some code examples of what you're trying to achieve? Your question is not 100% clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example from SAPUI5 Explored:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBar/code

As you can see in the file IconTabBar.view.xml you can set keys for every IconTabFilter. This key should be filled by your binding.

In the IconTabBar.controller.js the handler for the IconTabBarSelect event is implemented. Just read the selected key and act accordingly.

If that does not answer your question, you could post some code examples to clarify your problem.